# How to append parameter to given url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to append some value to given URL.
Suppose var name = "ABC";

I want to append ABC to url say "http://www.mysite.com"

How to append name "ABC" to above url??

Comment: 10 questions. 0 accepted questions. Not really encouraging anyone to answer this … although the answer can be found near the start of every JS tutorial out there anyway …

Answer (score 3):

You normally use a query string for this kind of thing:

```
http://www.mysite.com?name=ABC
```

The part after the ? is called the query string or the "search".

You concatenate the search terms with "&", e.g.,

```
http://www.mysite.com?name=ABC&type=1&level=4
```

Not included is the "hash", delimited by the # character, which references a portion of the page and comes last. For exampe,

```
http://www.mysite.com?name=ABC#part1
```